# jQuery working with multiple tabs group

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page with multiple tabs. But if you copy/paste the code and view in Chrome, you'll understand exactly what I am talking about. When the page loads, I'd want to show the tabs which correspond to [Manage Roles]. Then when the user clicks on the [Manage Roles-Person Associations] or [Manage Application-Data Package Association], I'd want to display the corresponding tabs.

The following is the code which I've used so far. The problem that I come across is that when I click on the link on the left, the page is reverted back to the [Manage Roles] tabs which I completely understand since I've coded everything in the $(document).ready function. But I can't figure out how to get it to work the way I want it to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<body>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#divRolesTabs').tabs();
        $('#divRolesPersonsAssociations').hide();
        $('#divManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation').hide();

        $('#sManageRoles').click(function () {
            $('#divRolesTabs').tabs();
            $('#divRolesTabs').show();

            $('#divRolesPersonsAssociations').hide();
            $("#divManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation").hide();
        });

        $('#sManageRolesPersonAssociation').click(function () {
            $('#divRolesPersonsAssociations').show();
            $('#divRolesPersonsAssociations').tabs();
            $('#divRolesPersonsAssociations').focus();

            $('#divRolesTabs').hide();
            $("#divManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation").hide();
        });

        $('#sManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation').click(function () {
            $("#divManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation").show();
            $("#divManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation").tabs();

            $('#divRolesTabs').hide();
            $('#divRolesPersonsAssociations').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<form id="frmAdminView" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divNavigationPane">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=""><span id="sManageRoles">Manage Roles</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><span id="sManageRolesPersonAssociation">Manage Roles-Person Associations</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><span id="sManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation">Manage Application-Data Package Associations</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="divRolesTabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#divAddRoles"><span>Add Roles</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#divDeleteRoles"><span>Delete Roles</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#divChangeRoles"><span>Change Roles</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="divAddRoles">
                        <p>Add Roles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDeleteRoles">
                        <p>Delete Roles</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divChangeRoles">
                        <p>Change Roles</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divRolesPersonsAssociations">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#divAssignRoles"><span>Add Roles</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#divDeleteRoleAssociations"><span>Delete Roles</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="divAssignRoles">
                        <p>Assign Roles to persons</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDeleteRoleAssociations">
                        <p>Delete Role Associations</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="divManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#divAddApplications"><span>Add Applications</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#divAddDataPackage"><span>Add Data Package</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#divAddApplicationDataPackageAssociations"><span>Add Application/Data Package</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="divAddApplications">
                        <p>Add Applications</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divAddDataPackage">
                        <p>Add Data Packages</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divAddApplicationDataPackageAssociations">
                        <p>Add App Data Package Association</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the answer is to return false from your click handlers:

```
$('#sManageRoles').click(function () {
    $('#divRolesTabs').tabs();
    $('#divRolesTabs').show();

    $('#divRolesPersonsAssociations').hide();
    $("#divManageApplicationDataPackageAssociation").hide();

    return false;
});
```

When you don't return 'false' from the click handler, the default anchor tag functionality kicks in which means (since you haven't specified an href) the page is reloaded.